# Access VBA: this application has requested the Runtime

Tags: ms-access, vba

Running a VBA macro, sometimes it works well. But in some cases, I get the following error.

[image]

I have debugged the code but I don't get any error. The code is the following.

```
Public Sub Adjust_ComboBox()
On Error GoTo Adjust_ComboBox_Err

    Dim mes As Form
    Set mes = [Form_Treatment Details]


    Dim count As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ctl In mes.Detail.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            Dim comboitems() As Variant
            count = 1
            comboitems = ctl.Value
            count = UBound(comboitems) + 1
            ctl.Height = (300 * count)
            Erase comboitems
        End If
    Next


Adjust_ComboBox_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Adjust_ComboBox_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Adjust_ComboBox_Exit

End Sub
```

How can it be possible to get this error?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is hiding any VBA error messages you may be getting - all that happens there is it tries to execute a line, can't due to an error so it goes onto the next line which it often can't execute because the previous line had an error and so on - nothing you expected happens because of the error you told it not to show you.  [This link](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) is very helpful in how to reference a form as well.

Comment: In addition to Darren's comments, pretty sure you should be using Set mes = Form_Treatment_Details.  You've kind of mixed two object naming methods, you use the brackets when refering to the name as a string that has a space i.e. "[Treatment Details]" or a child of a class i.e. Forms. [Treatment Details]  VBA replaces spaces with the _ character for object names and appends Form_ to the beginning of forms.  Look in the Object Explorer for the specific name VBA uses.

Answer (score 0):

This whole block of code looks odd to me.

```
Dim comboitems() As Variant
count = 1
comboitems = ctl.Value
count = UBound(comboitems) + 1
ctl.Height = (300 * count)
Erase comboitems
```

My questions are:

- Why are you DIMing and ERASEing the combotems in a loop?
- Why are you setting your array to the control's value?
- Are you trying to set the height based on the number of items?
- Why are you setting `count=1` when it just gets overwritten two lines
  later?

If I am guessing right on the answers to the questions I think you'd eliminate a few possible crashes by slimming down your loop code and using ListCount:

```
count = ctl.ListCount
if count > 0 then
    ctl.Height = (300 * count)
else
    ctl.Height = 300
end if
```